# Problem with feeds taxonomy import

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds

Why is that I cant import taxonomy terms with feeds, it says it imported 23 terms, but they are nowhere to be found....

I used term name, url alias, term id in mapping then imported it via feeds, nothing happens, it says that the terms were imported but tehy are not

vocabolary is called category...

Comment: I have the same issue.  The data is in the database for each field but taxonomy_term_data is empty.

Comment: Just ran into same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to auto-create the term in the feeds field mapping, and/or in the vocabulary option "auto-create" term.